# Como adicionar Diretório à variável Path do Windows durante a instalação?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows, path, setup

Desenvolvi uma aplicação do tipo *Console* em C# com o Visual Studio 2013 e queria que o instalador adicionasse o diretório da solução na variável `Path` do Windows, durante a instalação. Isso é possível? Qual o procedimento para realizar essa alteração no sistema?

**Obs.:** Não estou utilizando instaladores de terceiros, apenas o Visual Studio 2013. Notei que o 2010 já tem um gerador de Setup, porém o 2013 só tem o Publish.

Comment: Para que seria o uso disso?

Comment: A minha aplicação é do tipo _Console_.

Comment: O instalador é o do próprio VS ou de terceiros?

Comment: No caso o do VS. Na verdade estou estudando C# agora, e é o meu primeiro programa com o VS, não sei bem se estou procedendo da maneira correta, mas a princípio estou utilizando apenas o VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013) não possui um gerador de *Setup* (Apenas o *Publish*), conforme tinha o [visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010). Por isso eu utilizei a extensão [Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d).

Após a instalação da extensão, adicionei ao meu projeto um projeto `Setup Project` localizado em `Other Project Types > Visual Studio Installer` (opção criada pela [extensão](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)).

Adicionei uma nova Classe ao meu projeto chamada `InstallerActions.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GiTp
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class InstallerActions : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {

        public override void Install(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Install(savedState);
        }


        public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Rollback(savedState);
        }

        public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);

            if (this.Context.Parameters["cpath"] == "1")
                AddPath(this.Context.Parameters["targ"]);
        }

        public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            Process application = null;
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (!process.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("gitp")) continue;
                application = process;
                break;
            }

            if (application != null && application.Responding)
                application.Kill();

            RemovePath(this.Context.Parameters["targ"]);

            base.Uninstall(savedState);
        }

        private void AddPath(String path)
        {
            var originalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").TrimEnd(';');
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", originalPath + ';' + path.TrimEnd('\\'), EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
        }

        private void RemovePath(String path)
        {
            var originalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").TrimEnd(';');

            List<string> paths = new List<string>(originalPath.Split(';'));

            foreach (string p in paths)
            {
                if (String.Compare(p, path, true) == 0)
                {
                    paths.Remove(p);
                    break;
                }

            }

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", String.Join(";", paths) );
        }
    }
}
```

O método `AddPath(String path)` realiza o registro da variável `PATH` e é chamado no método `Commit`, que é executado após a instalação do programa.

Os parâmetros `this.Context.Parameters["cpath"]` e `this.Context.Parameters["targ"]` são informados na propriedade `CustomActionData` do *Custom Event* da extensão, conforme ilustração:

[image: Custom Action Commit]

<sub>**Valor da propriedade:** `/targ="[TARGETDIR]\" /cpath=[CHECKPATH]`.

**Obs.:** A propriedade `CHECKPATH` é um *checkbox* de uma tela customizada do *Setup*.</sub>

O método `RemovePath(String path)` remove o registro da variável `PATH` e é chamado no método `Uninstall`, que será executado na desinstalação do programa.

<sub>**Obs.:** A configuração da propriedade `CustomActionData` é a mesma do *Commit*, exceto que não é necessário o envio da propriedade `CHECKPATH`.</sub>

---

**Fontes**

1. [Creating an MSI/Setup Package for C# Windows Application Using a Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project <sup>EN</sup>](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Setup-Package-for-Csharp-Windows)
2. [Resposta do @CiganoMorrisonMendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65502/8493)

Answer (score 5):

Para o instalador feito via ***"Inno Setup"***, poderia ser feito dessa maneira
adicionando a *section* [Registry].

> Setting Environment Variables
>
> *Environment variables are stored as string values in the registry, so it is possible to manipulate them using the [Registry] section. System-wide environment variables are located at:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
> User-specific environment variables are located at:
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment*

Referência: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#env

Comment: Pra mim criar um instalador com o _Inno Setup_ eu compilo meu código e crio o _setup_ com os arquivos compilados, ou ele compila?

Comment: Isso você compila seu código normalmente, ai no inno você adiciona os arquivos que você precisa, Readme, Licença e coisas afim. No inno setup é possivel até checar se tem framework instalado na maquina, e instalar caso seja necessario. Ele é bem simples olha ai: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1244/criando-um-pacote-de-instalacao-com-o-inno-setup.aspx

@KaduAmaral

Answer (score 4):

Você pode escrever um aplicativo que faça isso em C#:

Usando [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var originalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "C:\\Minha\\Aplicacacao\\Console.exe;" + originalPath);
```

Só funciona se o aplicativo executar em modo elevado.

Se for gerar um `.msi` usando [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/), [veja a parte de Environment](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/environment.html).

---

**EDIT**

Aparentemente `PATH` é um caso especial de variável de ambiente. O recomendado é alterá-la através de modificações no registro do Windows:

```
string chave = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment";         
string pathAntigo = (string)Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(chave).GetValue("Path", "", RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);

Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(chave).SetValue("Path", pathAntigo + ";C:\\Minha\\Aplicacacao\\Console.exe;", RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
```

Comment: Esse modo elevado é como quando o programa é executado em modo de administrador? Esse aplicativo deveria estar junto com minha solução?

Comment: @KaduAmaral Isso mesmo. Se você vai fazer por instalador, é melhor usar o método do instalador, que já faz tudo pra você. A ideia era mostrar que é possível alterar as variáveis de ambiente usando C# também.

Comment: O instalador do VS permite que quando a instalação da solução seja terminada esse "configurador" seja executado (e em modo elevado)? Se sim teria como adicionar os passos pra isso na sua resposta? :)

Comment: Eu reparei que no Visual Studio, em `New > Project > Other Projects Types > Setup and Deployment` possui um tipo "Enable InstallShield Limited Edition" seria possível fazer com ele?

Comment: Acho que sim: http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/IHelpISXSetEnvVariable.htm

Comment: Opa Cigano, eu utilizei desta forma, até criei um arquivo de log, ele adiciona tudo certinho, porém quando eu vou nas propriedades do computador e vou nas variáveis de ambiente, não está a alteração, nem na do sistema nem na do usuário...

Comment: @KaduAmaral Não sei exatamente o que pode ser. Coloquei uma solução alternativa.

Comment: Descobri, eu adicionei o terceiro parâmetro `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` e funcionou... :)

Comment: Cigano, obrigado pela ajuda, mas eu vou responder à pergunta com os passos que eu fiz até chegar na parte que você me ajudou, pois está incompleta a resposta, considerando o escopo "durante a instalação" da pergunta.

Comment: Cigano pode me dar uma ajuda [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/135360?noredirect=1)?